# How do I load JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

Thanks.

UPDATE 1
Thanks! So I use this↓
But it has warning "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " ;(

```
<script>
(function(){
   var nytg = nytg || {}
   $.getJSON("test.json", function(error,root) {
     nytg.ipoData = root
     console.log(root)
   })
 }());  
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have any JSON data in that code snippet. Where are you loading it from?  Are you wanting to use `nytg.ipoData` as JSON (it's an actual javascript array of objects right now).  Explain what you're trying to do in more detail and what the JSON is (isn't).

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
 var nytg = nytg || {};
 nytg.ipoData = [{"fulldate":200704,"NAME":"SWU","rMVOP":1000,"Obs":80,"BHRET3":1.333},{"rMVMP":97.517,"fulldate":19810305,"NAME":"AUTOCLAVE ENGINEERS","rMVOP":97.517,"Obs":74,"BHRET3":-6.31},{"rMVMP":56.9845,"fulldate":19810319,"NAME":"OBJECT RECOGNITION","rMVOP":50.6529,"Obs":75,"BHRET3":-18.34},{"rMVMP":24.0698,"fulldate":19810324,"NAME":"HEI","rMVOP":22.2646,"Obs":76,"BHRET3":-22.963}];

Comment: ↑Actually, this is my original code. But i really want to ues json file. But I don't know how to use json ;( Why My mornitor is always white?

Answer (score 1):

i have created a demo for your ref [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/xDAEyp8B1zXEDtMEOrnL)

in it i copy all your array in a file named "data.json"

In index file i load script.js file, which use jquery's "getJSON" method to load json file

```
 (function(){
   var nytg = nytg || {};
   $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
     nytg.ipoData = data
     console.log(data)
   })
 }());
```

hope this will help you

UPDATE 1:

remove

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.json">
```

this is not required because you are loading this file using getJSON method

UPDATE 2:

add this in your head section

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. really Thanks.
But I have 3 problems.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $$ is not defined 
Uncaught ReferenceError: NYTD is not defined

Comment: see "UPDATE 1" section in my answer hope this will help

Comment: Thanks! But i still have warning. So please see my UPDATE 1

Comment: i think you don't have jquery, please see "UPDATE 2"